# How to get Youtube video json list under an user via Google V3 API

Tags: youtube-api

In V2, I can use: http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/?alt=json&author=XXX

However, V2 has been deprecated and can not be used anymore.

What's the correct replacement in Google API V3?

Answer (score 0):

You should get your API key (for server or for client).
    http://code.google.com/apis/console#access

And use `https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&channelId={CHANNEL_ID}&key={YOUR_API_KEY}`
    https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list

**But, there are some bug reports about this API now.**
    https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=6598
    https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=6599
    https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=6600